# activate logging output in xamarin studio

Tags: logging, xamarin.ios, nunit, xamarin.android, xamarin

I write UnitTests (no integration-tests with device and stuff) for monotouch and monodroid in xamarin studio with NUnit.

That works great, besides the problem that I don't see any log output created by `Debug.WriteLine`.

Does anybody know how to activate that in xamarin studio?

Thx!

Comment: I would also like to know how to get break points working as well.

Comment: @BenBishop I think I can help you here. Just right-click in your xamarin studio Unit Tests-window on the test and choose "Run Tests With" -> "Mono Soft Debuger". Not the best way but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone had posted this answer, but removed it for whatever reason. I'm reposting it for prosperity sake...

Debug.WriteLine does not seem to work in the Xamarin Studio, but Console.WriteLine does. With this in mind, you can do the following:

```
#if __ANDROID__ || __IOS__
     Debug.WriteLine("My trace statement");
#else
     Console.WriteLine("My trace statement");
#end if
```

Comment: on android, Debug.WriteLine was not usefull for me (logs will not be saved on the device). I use there something like that `Android.Util.Log.Debug("win4youthApp",formatedMessageWithLevel);`

Comment: I will also add that you can use the `DepencyService` and an `Interface` in a `PCL` project to send text to the `Console.WriteLine` statements on each platform.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your unit test SetUp

```
ConsoleTraceListener c = new ConsoleTraceListener (true);
Trace.Listeners.Add (c);
```

`Debug.Trace()` will write messages, but you need the above listener to take those messages and send them to the console.

The output appears in the Test Results, Output panel

Comment: Thx dale, thats a great solution! Even simpler than the accepted one.